# Test rules for algorithms implementation, what are they?

Tags: algorithm, testing, implementation, fsm, decomposition

I wonder, how could I test my implementation of any given algorithm?

What are the different options for the test approach?

1. Is algorithm decomposing on determinate / non-determinate final state machine required?
2. Unit-testing?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the first test to perform is usually to verify the implementation against a (big enough) set of known test vectors. This is more or less unit testing.

If the implementation is not too complex, one can also construct mathematical proof that the implementation transforms the given, known set of pre-conditions into the given, known set of post-conditions. This is the most complete way to ensure an algorithm/implementation is correct, albeit probably the most hard to do for reasonably complex implementations.